# Can we use MongoRespository for findByNameAndPassword() this type of queries?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mongorepository

```
Optional<TicketUserDto> ticketuser=ticketUserDao.findByUserIdAndPassword(userId, password);
```

DAO:

```
@Repository
public interface TicketUsersDao extends MongoRepository<TicketUserDto, Serializable> {
    Optional<TicketUserDto> findByUserIdAndPassword(String userId, String password);
}
```

And here is the DTO definition

```
@Document(collection="ticket_users") 
public class TicketUserDto { 
    private String userId; 
    private String password; 

    public String getUserId() { return userId; } 
    public void setUserId(String userId) { this.userId = userId; } 

    public String getPassword() { return password; } 
    public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password; }

    @Override public String toString() { 
        return "TicketUserDto [userId=" + userId + 
            ", password=" + password + "]"; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please post the definition of `TicketUserDto` to help us understand what's going on.

Comment: when i call findAll() iam getting the values but when i try to fetch with 2parameters like findByUserIdAndPassword then iam getting null

Comment: The class definition should be added as an edit, not as a comment.

Comment: Never add code as image. Add code as text. Please take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question instead of posting it as comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i get that 
i added @field then i get the values

```
 @Field(value="userId")
private String userId;
@Field(value="password")
private String password;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your find method should look as it follows:

```
Optional<TicketUserDto> findOptionalByUserIdAndPassword(String userId, String password);
```

Also, your class does not declare a primary key. To make it work you should refactor your classes as it follows:

```
@Document(collection="ticket_users") 
public class TicketUserDto { 
    @Id
    private String userId; 
    /* the other code remains untouched */
}

@Repository
public interface TicketUsersDao extends MongoRepository<TicketUserDto, String> {
    Optional<TicketUserDto> findOptionalByUserIdAndPassword(String userId, String password);
}
```

Comment: still getting null

Comment: still getting null only

Comment: How do you test this class? I have reproduced the code in my editor and I get the object correctly.